# calculating exponential function with high precision.

Tags: exponential-function, machine-precision

How can I calculate $e^{-x}$ with 128 bit precision. I am using c on a machine of 32 bit wordsize.
Thank you.

Comment: The Taylor serie $e^x= 1 + \frac x {1!}+ \frac {x^2} {2!} + ...$

Comment: Although I have provided an answer, this really isn't a question for Math.StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the [Gnu MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/).  There, the function you are interested in is [`mpfr_exp()`](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Special-Functions).

Comment: I know about the GNU MPFR library but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Ishan : Lot's of ways.  However, I don't propose that you reinvent the wheel.